# How to iterate alphabet in order from an array, per append (onlick)

Tags: jquery

I want to Iterate alphabet instead of numbers in jquery. Is it possible from an array ? I am sharing my code here :

```
let alp = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
  alp = alp[0];
  ++alp;
  $(this).parents('.card').find("#getOpEle").append('<div><input type="text" value="'+alp+'" 
  </div>');
```

Comment: A [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) statement?  Maybe [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: In this case, you could probably use `.map`:  `$("#getOpele").append(alp.map((i,e)=> \`<div>${e}</div>\`))` without the need to "iterate" (manually)

Comment: for loop works, but I want only one component per append. for example : If I click and append the component once, it will get a, if click again and append again, it will get b that case and so on

Comment: Perhaps you could review your question and **add what you actually want**.  There's no mention of "one component per append" or even clicking.

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of a generator function? (Just for fun :) )

```js
function* generateAlp() {
  const alp = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
  for (let i = 0; i < alp.length; i++) {
    const html = `
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value="${alp[i]}"
        />
      </div>
    `
    yield html
  }
}

const getAlp = generateAlp()

const btnAppendAlp = document.getElementById('btn-append-alp')
const container = document.getElementById('alp-container')

btnAppendAlp.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const newAlp = getAlp.next().value
  if (newAlp) {
    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + newAlp
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="btn-append-alp">APPEND NEW ALP</button>

<div id="alp-container">
</div>
```